# nginx pretty rewriting one parameter

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a simple rewrite rule, but I can't get it to work (even with all the other answers here on SO)

I want the user to open this url:

```
www.example.com/mypage/abcd
```

and nginx should rewrite it to:

```
www.example.com/myrealpage/index.html?link=abcd
```

so actually I want my `link` parameter nicely embedded in the url.
This is the rule that almost works:

```
location /mypage { 
    rewrite ^/mypage/(.*)$ /myrealpage/index.html?link=$1 last;
}
```

It seems to work for the `index.html` file, **but now all script and css imports are broken** . Because every `js/script.js` or `css/style.css` becomes rewritten to `mypage/abcd/css/style.css` which obviously doesn't exist.

FYI:
I apparently need that rewrite `mypage` → `myrealpage` because my server provider automatically generates an `alias` config file that already contains a `location /myrealpage` so, I don't see any other option than just renaming it to add my own `location` rule.

How
can I alter that url to rewrite this one `link` parameter? It is only the one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You're rewriting every path to your /mypage directory. If you keep your scripts outside in a parent directory you'll be just fine.